# I would like to round a variable to the nearest 0.5 decimal in python

Tags: python-3.x

For instance, 1.3 should be 1.5, 1.15 should be 1, 2.8 should be 3, etc...in python

Comment: multiply *2, add 0.5 and then call floor. Divide the result by 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 import math

 def round(num):
     return math.floor(num * 2 + 0.5) / 2

 print round(1.3)    # 1.5
 print round(1.15)    # 1.0
 print round(2.8)    # 3.0
```

as mention by -Christoph Bimminger-

Comment: Thanx for your prompt responce, Thanx a lot Christoph